# Table editing in Wordpress

Tags: table

I'm using a table in Wordpress to get my spacing right, but I'd like to remove the border completely or make it white so it isn't visible anymore. If anyone knows how to do that I'd appreciate it. I've tried a bunch of ways to do it and just can't. The web address is www.hrms.co.za (but it is still under construction)

Comment: This is a rather general HTML/CSS question, so probably better fit for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Anyways, have [you searched for this](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=css+table+remove+border) already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a custom CSS.

Go to "Appearance > Customize > Additionnal CSS" and add this :

```
td,tr {
    border: none!important;
}
```

it will get rid of all table border

Comment: Thank you. This has done the trick. Will it apply to any table I create going forward, and is the Additional CSS an area to apply general rules to the whole site?

Comment: @TimForssman yes this CSS tab is general for all the websites, but of course we can restrict the CSS to only the element we want by using more complex CSS selector but the one i gave will now apply to all the tables ;)

Comment: Thanks so much. I'll do some research into the CCS. I didn't actually know about it. Early days still